# Spring Boot BDD Testing with serenity

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, spring-boot, bdd

we have a spring boot application which we want to test via serenity (former Thucydides). Theoretically the tests can be run (if i test for example www.google.com everything works fine) but I want to test my own application and not google ;)

So I need to start the application before running the tests. Normally we have an annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

at our test class. but with Serenity and cucumber we need

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
```

and it is not possible to add 2 @RunWith annotations.

What is the best way to get the tests wit Serenity and Cucumber running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Spring 4.2.1 and you should be able to use the Serenity runner:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-junit4-rules